# I am facing a BeanCreationException after deploying service.xml which builds successfully

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, liferay, liferay-ide

```
    14:48:32,427 ERROR [pool-2-thread-6][ContextLoader:227] Context initialization failed
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liferayHibernateSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;`

     nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SystemException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortletContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortletContextLoaderListener.java:98)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:77)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:40)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:151)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:141)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:52)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1099)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1621)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SystemException
```

1. Added jars and hibernate mappings or configuration files to the project.
2. Checked build path for missing jars.
3. It is getting stuck when portal.properties and service.properties get deployed.
4. I am able to build service successfully and compile the portlet as well, it causes error when deploying on server.

Answer (score -1):

Note that the class in question is `SystemException`, not `com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException`. Most likely you've declared it somewhere without the necessary import statement, or just not fully qualified. Check your code for those occurrences.